# Detect chinese character in a string VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, split, cjk

Is there a way to detect a Chinese character in a string which is build like this:

```
dim test as string = "letters 中國的"
```

Now I want to substring only the Chinese characters. But my code is database driven, so I can't substring it, because the length is always different. So is there a way I can split the string, from the moment I detect a Chinese character?

Comment: check whether the byte value of each character is in the chinese character range

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! Can you give me an example? or a tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use regexp like in the following example, didn't test and I haven't code using VB.net for years So syntax may be not correct.

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(value, "[\u4e00-\u9fa5]+", 
                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

' If successful, write the group.
If (m.Success) Then
    Dim key As String = m.Groups(1).Value

End If
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx